# How to generate a matrix with variable which will be then used for further computations

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I am solving a dispersion equation of multilayer plate. According to the number of layers,I have to generate,let´s say,prescription of a matrix in which will be two variables - frequency and velocity. So, in the first step, I will generate a matrix and in the second step,the matrix will be used for further calculations in loops, which will be related to these variables.

I will roughly demonstrate the problem on a function:

```
def function(a,b):
    y=a*f+b*c
    return y
```

(a and b will be defined in the input,but f and c will be still variables)

`function(a,b)` will return me the prescription of a function with two variables - `f` and `c`.

Then, I will use the prescription of a function to calculate its value for different f and c values.

In my case I have to use this approach, becaulse the shape of the matrix will be related to the number of present layers. Ithought,that I can use symbolic toolbox, but I think that this won´t be the right way how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you need a factory - a function that returns another function:

```
def prescription_factory(a,b):
    return lambda f,c: a*f+b*c

# Create a function:
prescription = prescription_factory(10,20)

# Use the new function
prescription(1,2)
# 50
```